# Python 3.4 Matching a string with a list of strings (in the form of keys from a dictionary) **ignoring case.**

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, dictionary, ignore-case

The scenario: I have a dictionary of items:

```
d = {'abcde': 1, 'ETHAN': 2, 'dogsAndcats': 3, 'cat and MOUSE': 4}
```

I ask the user to input one of the four key values of the dictionary d:

```
user_input = input()
```

Then I take their value and check it against each key name in the dictionary:

```
for key in d.keys():
    if user_input == key:
        return True
```

Lets assume the user is being somewhat friendly and is at least entering the correct spelling of the words. But! -This is the whole basis of my question- **the user neglects to use the correct capitalization.**

How can I check the user's input against my list **ignoring the capitalization?**

I tried using regular expression methods .search and .match. See the code below:

```
def check_value_in_dict(val, d): 
    for k in d.keys():
        if re.search(val, k, re.IGNORECASE):
            return True
```

This returns true if the user only enters one correct letter in the string. **It does not check the entire string which is necessary for my program**.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
if user_input.lower() == key.lower()
```

Comment: For whatever reason that never crossed my mind and I honestly don't know why. +1 thank you for the help

Comment: No problem, my pleasure!